# Case statement within select case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to create a `case` statement to work but I seem to be messing up the syntax somehow. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT lp.assign_date, CASE WHEN lp.assign_date > '01-JAN-13' 
THEN
  (select count(*) > 0 THEN 'BAD' ELSE 'GOOD' END
   FROM transaction_table
   WHERE ACCOUNT = :V_ACCT
   AND transaction_date < :V_TRAN_DATE
   AND transaction_code = :V_TRAN_CODE 
   AND :V_TRAN_CODE IN (1,6,25)
   AND attorney_id = :V_ATTY_ID)
ELSE
  (SELECT
   function_legal_chk(:V_ACCT, :V_TRAN_DATE)
   FROM dual)
FROM legal_placement lp;
```

Essentially its checking to see if the assigned date is after January, if it is then do the next `case statement` else do the `function`.

Here is the error that I am receiving:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
```

From what I know and research that I've done on `case statements`, my syntax seems to be correct but I am not sure if a `case` within a `case` is something that can be done.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be that `function_legal_chk` does not return a `char` and is hence incompatible? What's the error message?

Comment: Updated my question with the error message, totally forgot to add it the first time around. Thanks. To answer your question though, the `function` does return a `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is correct syntax:

```
SELECT lp.assign_date,
       (CASE WHEN lp.assign_date > '01-JAN-13' 
             THEN (select (CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN 'BAD' ELSE 'GOOD' END)
                   FROM transaction_table
                   WHERE ACCOUNT = :V_ACCT
                     AND transaction_date < :V_TRAN_DATE
                     AND transaction_code = :V_TRAN_CODE 
                     AND :V_TRAN_CODE IN (1,6,25)
                     AND attorney_id = :V_ATTY_ID
                 )
             ELSE function_legal_chk(:V_ACCT, :V_TRAN_DATE)
        END)
FROM legal_placement lp;
```

The nested `case` statement either has to be entirely in the subquery (as shown above) or entirely outside.  Your original has it half-and-half.  Also, you don't need a subquery to call a function in a `select`.  It is technically ok, but unnecessary.

Comment: Yes this seems to have done this trick. Thank you very much for your help! Also thanks letting me know that bit about not needed a `subquery` to call a `function` in this case.

Comment: It appears as though the OP is passing constants into the function. If this is the case then [scalar sub-query caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html) is a _very_ good reason to place it within a sub-select.

Comment: @Ben: It is *never* a good reason to make your code more complicated and less readable just for the sake of performance without measuring first.

Comment: If that was directed at me @inflagranti then I agree; I'm just pointing out that the complication is not necessarily either unneeded or unnecessary and that the seeming complication has a valid performance-based reason behind it (whether that actually happened in this case I've no idea).

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a syntax error in

```
select count(*) > 0 THEN 'BAD' ELSE 'GOOD' END
```

It should be

```
select CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN 'BAD' ELSE 'GOOD' END
```

Also, as pointed out by @GordonLindoff, you don't need the second subquery:

```
(SELECT
function_legal_chk(:V_ACCT, :V_TRAN_DATE)
FROM dual)
```

Can just be written as

```
function_legal_chk(:V_ACCT, :V_TRAN_DATE)
```

And finally, make sure `function_legal_chk` returns a `Varchar` (or `Char`) like it does in the first first `WHEN` expression, since they have to be that same type of course.

Comment: Yikes, such a silly thing to forget. Thank you for pointing that out!